# python asn1 structure unable to set field values

Tags: python, asn.1

I am trying to build an asn1 structure in python 3.7 using pyasn1 to serialize ECDSA signatures.

I have defined the following structure: (From an example found here http://snmplabs.com/pyasn1/)

```
class ASNBitcoinSignature(Sequence):
    componentType = NamedTypes(
        NamedType('r', Integer()),
        NamedType('s', Integer()),
    )
```

my code to encode the r and s values of the signature looks like this:

```
asn = ASNBitcoinSignature()
asn['r'] = self.r().x()
asn['s'] = self.s()
serialized = encode(asn)
```

Running the code I receive

```
'No field named "r" defined for ASNBitcoinSignature'
```

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong? Is this maybe an old example and the field values need to be set or defined in another way now?

Answer (score 0):

This error came from a wrong import of Sequence:

Originally I imported

```
from asn1crypto.core import Sequence
```

but what I actually wanted was

```
from pyasn1.type.univ import Sequence
```

A further problem with this code (just for future reference) was that the Integer type defined in pyasn1 had a too low maximum value for my use case.

I could solve this by creating a new Subtype of Integer like this:

```
class ASNBigInteger(Integer):
    subtypeSpec = ValueRangeConstraint(0x1, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141)
```

Comment: It seems there is no range constraint on pyasn1 `Integer`. I wonder how did you hit that...